# In xts::to.period() how to get week boundaries

Tags: r, xts

The xts reference for `to.period` says : 
"It is important to note that all dates will be aligned to the end of each period by default"

In the following I was hoping to see the output to show the 9/12 or 9/18 as the date output. But
obviously I am doing something not right. So what does "alignment" mean, and how can I get **week** boundaries?

```
x1 = xts(1.23, as.Date("2016-09-15"))

x1
           [,1]
2016-09-15 1.23

to.period(x1, period="weeks", indexAt="firstof")
           x1.Open x1.High x1.Low x1.Close
2016-09-15    1.23    1.23   1.23     1.23

to.period(x1, period="weeks", indexAt="lastof")
                    x1.Open x1.High x1.Low x1.Close
2016-09-15 00:00:00    1.23    1.23   1.23     1.23
```

however

```
to.period(x1, period="months", indexAt="lastof")
           x1.Open x1.High x1.Low x1.Close
2016-09-30    1.23    1.23   1.23     1.23
```

Thanks a lot.

I am using R 3.3.1 on Windows 10

Comment: have you tried ``to.weekly()``

Comment: Yes I did, but `to.weekly()` gives the same, Plus it does not seem to have the `indexAt` option.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the source for `to.period()` it calls `firstof()` and `lastof()`. It has special handling for months, years, quarters and days, but not weeks:

```
    if (indexAt == "lastof") {
        ix <- as.POSIXlt(c(.index(xx)), tz = indexTZ(xx))
        if (period %in% c("years", "months", "quarters", 
            "days")) 
            index(xx) <- as.Date(lastof(ix$year + 1900, ix$mon + 
              1))
        else index(xx) <- lastof(ix$year + 1900, ix$mon + 
            1, ix$mday, ix$hour, ix$min, ix$sec)
    }
```

When you look at the code for lastof (or firstof) you see there is no week handling, because of the way POSIX data handling works (year, month, day, hour, minute, second - there is no concept of weeks).

It seems `endpoints()` (which is called by `to.period()`) is the only place to have special weeks handling.

I think you could hack on your own weekly round-up/round-down. E.g. if the date is in POSIXct form (seconds since 1970), then divide by 604800 (the number of seconds in 7 days), either call `ceiling()` or `floor()`, then multiply by 604800.  (Er, I think you need to add on 259200 (second in 3 days) at the end, because Jan 1st 1970, the basis of POSIXct time, is a Thursday not a Sunday.)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the hint from Darren Cook, I decided on the following approach to re-index

```
x1 = xts(1.23, as.Date("2016-09-15"))    
x1
           [,1]
2016-09-15 1.23
index(x1) = index(x1) - .indexwday(x1) # day of week in [0,6]
x1
           [,1]
2016-09-12 1.23
```